# Fourier Coefficients - geometrical meaning

Tags: real-analysis

What does the $n^{th}$ Fourier coefficient of a continuous function tell about the function geometrically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Fourier coefficient represents a projection of the function along a respective harmonic.  That's why the integral for the coefficients is taken to be an inner product, and the expansion is like a vector expansion.